# Starting windows bundle from network-drive use not included JRE?

Tags: java, install4j, network-drive

I bundle a java program by using install4j and put the jre into the bundle as it is possible with install4j.

At our company we have the situation that every user must use a network share e.g. drive X: on windows where they start the java programm by using the EXE produced by install4j.

When we check with the process explorer on windows if the JRE is used or not we see that the local JRE of the machine is used and not the one from the drive X:

any experience?

Comment: You can execute the launcher from the command line with the argument `/create-i4j-log` to get a log file that contains information about the JRE search sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Thx!

I check this with your cmd argument and get errors.

[9:280] unpack done
[9:285] could not delete packed file (error 5)
[9:286] checking x:\appl\myapps\app\jre\lib\deploy.jar
[9:287] x:\appl\myapps\app\jre\bin\unpack200.exe
[9:288] -r "x:\appl\myapps\app\jre\lib\deploy.jar.pack" "x:\appl\myapps\app\jre\lib\deploy.jar"
[9:300] waiting for unpack200 to finish
[9:383] unpack done
[9:387] could not delete packed file (error 5)
....
**x:\appl\myapps\app has write protection.** 
This happens 18 times for other jar files in the JRE too.
....
[11:25] Unpacking JRE done
[11:27] checkJavaExe (g:\appl\myapps\app\jre\bin\java.exe, [out], 2, 2, 1)
[11:28] file exists
[11:29] tempPath is C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\
[11:30] tempFile is C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j4DF8.tmp
[11:672] Exit Code 1
[11:674] couldn't get version
[11:675] checkJavaExe returning 0
[11:677] Testing location  (type Y)
[11:678] checkJavaExe (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre\bin\java.exe, [out], 2, 2, 0)
[11:679] file exists
...starting from now I see that the local JRE is used...

Why happen this? Write protection? Wrong install4j config?
```